# New row entry for each user role using Shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I need help for the below. I was able to get to my current output but the further format change is causing trouble.

For my shell script , the current output is as below :-

```
Username  a
mail   a@mail
role ra1
role ra2
company ac
Username b
mail b@mail
role rb1
role rb2
company bc
```

I need it to be in the below format.

```
Username  mail          role  company
a                  a@mail    ra1    ac
a                  a@mail    ra2    ac
b                  b@mail    rb1    bc
b                  b@mail    rb2    bc
```

For each new role a new row needs to be added with the user attributes. The number of roles will vary for the user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this awk codes should give you a hand:

```
..your..output..|awk '/^Username/{name=$2}
    /^mail/{mail=$2}
    /^role/{r[$2]}
    /^company/{comp=$2;for(x in r)print name,mail,x,comp;delete(r)}'
```

With your example data, it outputs:

```
a a@mail ra1 ac
a a@mail ra2 ac
b b@mail rb1 bc
b b@mail rb2 bc
```